# LinkedIn API V2 - How to upload photo as binary file

Tags: php, linkedin-api, php-curl

I'm having trouble with the second step of uploading a post with a photo seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin).

```
$post_fields = array(
    'file' => '@' . $_FILES['file-attachment']['tmp_name']
        . ';filename=' . $_FILES['file-attachment']['name']
        . ';type='     . $_FILES['file-attachment']['type']
);

$upload_response = process_curl(array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $upload_url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_fields,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: Bearer '.$token, 'x-li-format: json','Content-Type: multipart/form-data'),
), true);
```

This is what my request looks like. I tried without using the `type=` line but that didn't change anything. I'm getting an empty response and a status code of 400.

I'm using the upload URL from step 1 so I know that should be correct.

What about my request looks wrong? I'm trying to follow the cURL example they gave in the documentation, but perhaps the format of my file isn't correct?

I have also tried making the file parameter of post fields just be the full file path but that gave a response of false.

Another thing for me to mention is the file path has spaces in it.

Answer (score 1):

You should include the sytem path of the file eg:user/myname/image.jpg.
Content type should be application/binary

Comment: That worked, thank you! I don't always have access to $_FILES object though. I'm publishing posts as well as scheduling posts. When we schedule a post we upload the file to S3. How can I use this URL to upload to LinkedIn? I can get the raw file data, but I don't know how I'd get the path if it's just a URL

Comment: Linkedin doesnt allow the  remote urls. The image shoud be in your server.Because they need absolute path of the image.Keep the copy of your image in your server.Once it posted you can unlink the image from your server.